# Survey plugin recommendations

Tags: plugins

What is a good plugin to do surveys for wordpress.

I can think of creating a custom contact form 7 - but i was having problem in the formatting and separating it from the body of the post visually.
and it doesn't store survey result in some document or spreadsheet, so eventually i'll have to track everything manually.

so - i am on the hunt for a survey specific plugin.
the questions are simple, i need option buttons, check boxes, text boxes - and like 10 questions max - nothing fancy.

Thanks in advance for the help

Suggestions other than poll-daddy are welcomed :)

Comment: Haha, shoot. I was about to say poll-daddy. At least I caught it this time... ;)

Comment: It would help if you provided a reason that you don't want to use poll-daddy.

Comment: limited answers per survey = 100  - hosted externally on poll daddy - requires separate account, so can be a bit more hassle to do if team of ppl on same blog and i am just exploring possibilities and don't want to get the same answer - poll daddy cuz already tried it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you try [google docs](http://docs.google.com/)? you can embed their form as iframe which is easiest solution.

Comment: There are several great tutorials explaining how to do just that.  [Here's one ...](http://www.jasonmorrison.net/content/2008/create-a-survey-or-poll-for-your-blog-with-google-docs-and-spreadsheets/)

Comment: hmm coolest idea so far :)

Comment: i wouldn't have thought of this and yet it turns out, for us,  this is definitely the way to go. this answer absolutely helped me out today. also +1 to EAMann for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Polldaddy is the least bad of wp survey plugins; but there are tons of other hosted survey services that have no prerequisites beyond needing to be able to insert a JavaScript.

http://www.google.com/search?q=online+survey

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's been a while since it was asked, so I'm wondering what you used in the end.

Have you tried [Total Feedback](http://www.totalfeedback.net/)? it's more of a kissinsights solution for Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

[Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com)

You can see a full review of the plugin [here](http://wpnuggets.com/wp-plugin-review/gravityforms/).